# Get focused list item in a ListView with SelectionMode=None

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a list like this:

```
    <ListView x:Name="MyList" SelectionMode="None" KeyDown="MyList_KeyDown">
        <ListView.Items>
            <x:String>Alfa</x:String>
            <x:String>Beta</x:String>
            <x:String>Gamma</x:String>
        </ListView.Items>
    </ListView>
```

In the key down event I want to know which item that is in focus. But since SelectionMode is none, SelectedItem is null. Is there some way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
    private void MyList_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var inFocus = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() as ListViewItem;

        if(inFocus?.Content != null)
        {
            //Selected data is now in inFocus.Content
        }
    }
```